# React use name in URL instead of page ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app that allows users to create a page like a blog post.

It works correctly as far as viewing the page. When a page is published, it will create a publicly shareable URL like this:

`http://localhost:3000/bob/page/1`

This is done using the following code:

## Publish.jsx

```
     const currentHost = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
     const pageURL = `/${this.props.appState.currentUser.username}/page/${this.props.appState.pageFormData.currentPage.id}`;
     const copyURL = (<Link to={pageURL}>{currentHost}{pageURL}</Link>)
```

However, instead of showing the page & page id which I get from App.js, I want to show the name of the page (think like the title of a WordPress post)

## App.js

Currently, my page id's are coming from where I set state in App.js

```
      pages: [],
      pageFormData: {
        currentPage: {
          page: {},
        },
      },
```

Instead of a Page ID, I now want to use the name from the siteFormData:

```
      sites: [],
      siteFormData: {
        name: '',
      },
```

Pages are posted with the following data:

```
 // POST PAGE
  postPage = async pageData => {
    const siteID = this.state.currentSiteId
    const page = await addPage(siteID, pageData)

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      pages: prevState.pages ? [...prevState.pages, page] : [page],
      pageFormData: {
        currentPage: page,
      },
    }))
    this.props.history.push('/publish')
  }
```

I've replaced the current line:

```
`/${this.props.appState.currentUser.username}/page/${this.props.appState.pageFormData.currentPage.id}
```

with:

```
const pageURL = `/${this.props.appState.currentUser.username}/${this.props.appState.siteFormData.name}`;
```

This generates a URL `http://localhost:3000/exampleuser/sitename`

In App.js, The working route which uses page ID is set up like this:

**Current URL Route (app.js)**

`<Route path="/:userid/page/:id?" render={props => <View {...props} />} />`

for my new route I'm trying this:

**New URL Route (app.js)**

`<Route path="/:userid/site/name" render={props => <View {...props} />} />`

This generates the desired URL `http://localhost:3000/exampleuser/sitename`

However, when I click the link I'm getting error 404 not found.

I went back and added a colon in the URL
    `<Route path="/:userid/:name" render={props => <View {...props} />} />`

This now pushes me to the view I want but it is stuck on loading as if it can't read the page conent.

The component which renders the publicly viewable URL however, requires the pageID:

## View.jsx

```
  getPage = async () => {
    const {
      match: { params },
    } = this.props;
    if (params.id) {
      const page = await getOnePage(params.id);
      this.setState({
        inputs: JSON.parse(page.content),
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        inputs: [],
      });
    }
  };
```

which takes the data from the backend:

## api.jsx

```
// Get one page
export const getOnePage = async id => {
  getToken();
  const resp = await api.get(`pages/${id}`);
  return resp.data;
};
```

This is beyond my level of experience, so I'm not sure if I'm passing the correct parameters in the Route for my URL.  Is there a way to use the site name as an alias for the URL or is there a simple method that I'm missing to get this fixed?

Comment: just use react-router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: @OnerT. it looks like OP *is* using `react-router` already.

Comment: sorry I didn't check well

Comment: If you can problemless get page ID you can add to same state names - if you need them in few places you can export route names in separate module. I saw in typescript projects route names / IDs are usually stored like this: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBATg9mALsAzlA3lAUFXUBEAFnBMPgDQ574AOAhgJ4DudANqxVbvnQMa8IQifFgC+QA Your problem is as I guess getting pageID from backend and passing it to shared global state - you have three ways to achieve that - you neet to do it in some parent component (maybe even root); use middleware or if can get page ID simply get exported names.

Comment: As you can see enum in Typescript defines object where object of key route ID returns route name and vice versa.